# No funciona instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram-api

Estoy intentando cargar las fotos de mi *Instagram* en mi sitio web y me es **imposible**.

Ya intenté de varias maneras posibles y seguí al pie de la letra lo dicho en http://instafeedjs.com/

¿Por qué no funciona?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
<title>Instagram Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="insta-wrap">
            <h1>Instagram feed</h1>
            <div id="insta-feed">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var userFeed = new Instafeed ({

        get: "user",
        userId: "2113176191",
        accessToken: '2113176191.1f23bb1.f223b9724cdb4b91b54cd812e9c444a5'
    });
    userFeed.run();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que logre apreciar el `ìd` del `div` contenedor deberia ser `<div id="instafeed"></div>` para que instafeed.js lo encuentre automaticamente. Ademas de eso en la documentación marca como requerida la propiedad `clientId` donde usted debe proveer un id de cliente valido obtenido desde  API de Instagram http://instagram.com/developer/register/

Puedes probar algo como esto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="insta-wrap">
            <h1>Instagram feed</h1>
            <div id="instafeed">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var userFeed = new Instafeed ({

        get: "user",
        userId: "2113176191",
        clientId: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
    });
    userFeed.run();
</script>
```

Saludos!! Espero que le sea de utilidad.